# How do I change the attribute values of an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, replace, element

I have a video element with attributes. All I want to do is change those attributes. How do I do this with javascript?

This is my video element with attributes

```
<video id="VideoElement" src="video/surfing.ogv" controls poster="images/surfing.jpg" width="480" height="300"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('VideoElement').src = 'myNewSrc.ogv'
```

Similarly, for other attributes. 
This solution does not require jQuery

Answer (score 2):

A non-jquery solution:

```
document.getElementById('VideoElement').attributename = newvalue;
```

Comment: So for instance, if I want to change the src="" attribute of the video element, I could just write:  document.getElementById('VideoElement').src = video/cycling;

Comment: `... .src = 'video/cycling';`, but otherwise, yes.